# Simple reusing a method to use less code error

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods

So I was wondering how to save on code here.  I wanted to use the `initializeCombatship()` so that I don't have to type  `CombatShip goliath = new CombatShip();` over and over.  I wanted to create the ship then give it 10 HP.  Thank you for your input.

```
public int HP { get;set; }

public int initializeCombatship()
{
    CombatShip goliath = new CombatShip(); //How do you make this public and not have to type this over and over?
    int HP = 10;
    return HP;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    initializeCombatship(); //won't let me just inherit goliath and HP
    int L = goliath.LaserHit() - 5;
    MessageBox.Show("Goliath hit by laser! You Ships HP = " + L + "");
}
```

Comment: Read up on variable scoping. Since you have declared the goliath variable inside of the initializeCombatship method, it is only available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use a [Lazy Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) pattern:

```
CombatShip _goliath = null;
CombatShip Goliath 
{
    get
    {
        if (_goliath == null)
        {
            _goliath = new CombatShip();
            _goliath.HP = 10;
            // or: _goliath = new CombatShip() { HP = 10 };
        }
        return _goliath;
    }
    set
    {
        _goliath = value;
    }
}
```

Now any time you reference the `Goliath` property it will create the `CombatShip` instance if it hasn't already done so.  When you want to close the current instance simply assign `null` to the `Goliath` property.

Lazy initialization can be useful as long as you manage the lifecycle of the object appropriately.  It can be used to spread out the costs of initializing a class with lots of contained objects, especially where some of those object that may or may not be needed during the life of the class.  Also handy as a shortcut in some cases.  It does come with a slight overhead however - calls to the get method aren't free.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was thinking , just trying to over complicate it as inheritance and methods.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling a method:

```
initializeCombatship();
```

But what does that method *do*?  It internally creates an object, but then doesn't do anything with that object.  So the object falls out of scope after the method completes and is gone.  All the method does is return an integer.  Which you don't use.

Then you try to use an object that doesn't exist:

```
goliath.LaserHit()
```

Nowhere in the *current* method is there an object named `goliath`, hence the error.

One option could be to return the object from your method:

```
public CombatShip initializeCombatship()
{
    CombatShip goliath = new CombatShip(); //How do you make this public and not have to type this over and over?
    goliath.HP = 10;
    return goliath;
}
```

Then save that returned object in a variable:

```
CombatShip goliath = initializeCombatship();
```

Then, on the next line, the variable `goliath` will exist and have an instance of the object returned by the method.

This starts to then look more like [a "factory" method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which is often used instead of constructors for a variety of reasons, depending on the needs of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Building on David's suggestion, your method could be:

```
public CombatShip initializeCombatship()
{
    return new CombatShip { HP = 10 };
}
```

There is no real need for a variable to hold the object you are returning.